# Changing PHP version from .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I am trying to change the PHP version by adding a handler to the .htaccess file in the root directory of the domain but it's not working, The server is throwing a 403 Forbidden Error.
However, changing from the Cpanel PHP Selector option worked fine. But I don't want to change the PHP version Globally on my server because some of my apps hosted on the server are using an older version of PHP which is 7.4.

Here is the handler I am using for PHP 8.1 on .htaccess

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Please let me know What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact code you are using when attempting to use PHP 7.4? What type of hosting are you using? A shared server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403 Forbidden error occurs primarily due to your wrong handler code.

Try this one and it should work fine.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php81 .php
```

or this

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php81___lsphp .php
```

Let me know in the comments if it works for you

Comment: Thanks! `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php81 .php` worked for me on Heart Internet Shared Hosting. The one with underscores, that I see everywhere, broke the site.

Answer (score 0):

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml .htm